# How to hide custom button on TabBarController in Swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift3, uitabbarcontroller

I have a `UITabBarController` with custom button in the middle of TabBar. But I get a weird behavior if I set `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true`.

[image]

I created `UITabBarController` programmatically in Swift 3.

Here is my code to create the custom middle button:

```
func setupMiddleButton() {
         let menuButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 48, height: 48))

         var menuButtonFrame = menuButton.frame
         menuButtonFrame.origin.y = view.bounds.height - menuButtonFrame.height
         menuButtonFrame.origin.x = view.bounds.width/2 - menuButtonFrame.size.width/2
         menuButton.frame = menuButtonFrame

         menuButton.layer.cornerRadius = menuButtonFrame.height/2
         view.addSubview(menuButton)

         menuButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "updatemoment"), for: .normal)
         menuButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(menuButtonAction), for: .touchUpInside)

         view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }

func menuButtonAction() {
     let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
     let vc: UINavigationController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NewPostID") as! UINavigationController

     self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
     print("segue success")
}
```

How to fix that? I want the middle button to stay in the `BottomBar`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to fix it by:

Instantiating the menu button in the class:

```
let menuButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 64, height: 64))
```

Adding two function in the same controller (TabBarController):

```
func hideTabBar() {
    self.tabBar.isHidden = true
    self.menuButton.isHidden = true
}

func showTabBar() {
    self.tabBar.isHidden = false
    self.menuButton.isHidden = false
}
```

And then, whenever you need to hide or show the tabBar, use:

```
let tabBar = self.tabBarController as! InitialViewController
tabBar.showTabBar()
```

I'm currently using it in viewWillAppear and viewWillDisappear in some controllers.